# PHP/MySQL - creating avatar upload function for users using BLOB

Tags: php, mysql, blob, avatar

I am creating a forum and am currently trying to allow my users to be able to update their profile picture (avatar). I am attempting to do this with BLOB. I am aware that storing images on a database is not a good idea but this is just a self-learning project and will unlikely be considered for real life use in the future.

I am currently coming across the issue of the image not being saved in the database and resulting in the following error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: user_avatar in C:\wamp64\www\Latest_try\editprofile.php on line 24
```

I am a newb in php (clearly) and would appreciate if someone could help me understand what i  need to make it save the image to the database.

I also wonder if i can save the image like this or would i need a complete seperate table that could then somehow link to the users information using a foreign key.

Below is mysql table i am using in relation to the function and the issue.

```
mysql -> describe users;
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+--------------+
| Field           | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra        |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+--------------+
| user_Id         | int(8)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |auto_increment|
| user_name       | varchar(30) | NO   |     | NULL    |              |
| user_pass       | varchar(255)| NO   |     | NULL    |              |
| user_email      | varchar(255)| NO   |     | NULL    |              |
| user_date       | datetime    | NO   |     | NULL    |              |
| user_level      | int(8)      | NO   |     | NULL    |              |
| user_description| varchar(255)| YES  |     | NULL    |              |
| user_avatar     | longblob    | NO   |     | NULL    |              |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+--------------+
8 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

And here is my code for editprofile.php file.

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
include 'header.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION['signed_in']))
{
//the user is not logged in.
echo 'You must be <a href="/Latest_try/signin.php">Signed in</a> to add an image to your profile.'; 
}
else
{
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']!='POST')
{
echo '<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Choose Image: <input type="file" name="user_avatar"><br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
</form>';
}
else
{
    $query = "INSERT INTO
                        users(user_avatar)
                    VALUES
                        ('" . mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['user_avatar']) . "',
                              NOW(),
                              '" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "')";

$result=mysqli_query($link, $query);
if($result===false)
{
    mysqli_error($link);
}
     else
     {
         echo 'Your avatar has been updated!';
     }      
}
}
?>
```

Comment: For input type file we use `$_FILES['user_avatar']['name']`

Comment: Will keep it in mind. Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Be warned that your code is open to SQL injection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already know, saving images in the DB is a bad practice. However, the issue you are having is due to incorrect variable used. Check the below statement:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO
          users(user_avatar)
          VALUES
          ('" . mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_FILES['user_avatar']['name']) . "',
          NOW(),
          '" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "')";
```

You can also refer more about this [here](http://phppot.com/php/mysql-blob-using-php/).

Comment: Thanks. Its my first time coming across this variable "$_FILES" does that mean i do not require this string ?   "if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']!='POST')"

Comment: @Richard you can use that to check if its a posted page or not but for your need, you would prefer using `if(count($_FILES) > 0` as shown in the link I have shared in the answer.

Comment: @Richard if any of the answers worked, mark as an answer and upvote :)

Answer (score -1):

That's really bad practice saving pictures in your database columns.Instead save it in folder which is in the same directory as your project and the name of picture save to databse!!

Comment: I am more than aware of that but for learning purposes it would be nice to know how BLOB functions from my personal opinion.

Comment: This does not answer the given question. The given error message has a completely different source